# Unit test that an exception has been caught and handled

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mocking, mockito

I have written a method which uses BufferedReader and FileReader, and a result of this is that FileNotFoundException and IOException need to be handled.

Now I have utilised try and catch statements within my class to handle the exceptions so no issues there.

What I am having an issue with is writing a test which verifies that the exceptions have been caught.

I can't write a test as follows because my method already catches the exception so it is not propagated to be dealt with in the test:

```
@Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
public void testFileNotFound() {
    ...
};
```

How could I test that the exception has been caught? Would I need to create a mock object of my class and verify that the exception has been caught using something like Mockitio? Or not create a mock and use Mockitio to spy on the actual object to verify if the exception has been caught?

EDIT: Here's the method that I want to test...

```
public List<String[]> parse(String fileToRead) {

    BufferedReader fileReader = null;
    List<String[]> parsedData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String currentLine;

    try {
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToRead));

        while ((currentLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parsedLine = currentLine.split(",");
            parsedData.add(parsedLine);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("File does not exist", e);
    }
    return parsedData;
}
```

Comment: `expected` means you expect it to be thrown. If it's caught, you test by verifying the rest of the method logic, after it's been caught.

Comment: Show us a minimal but relevant example of the method under test.

Comment: Added an example of the method which I wish to test

Comment: I think you're looking at this the wrong way. You don't need to verify the exception gets caught. The compiler and/or your IDE are capable of figuring that out. What you need--and what the point of a good unit test is--is to verify that your code works as expected if/when the exception is thrown. If, for example, you need to distinguish "non-existent file" from "empty file", you'd write tests for those circumstances.

Comment: @dcsohl Ah, of course! That makes sense. In the method which I have written, a list of files are read. For my test I pass in a list of files, some which exist and some which don't but then I should simply assert that the files that do exist were successfully read.

Comment: Seconding dcsohl, there's no reason for your test to check _how_ your component is implemented—you just need to ensure that the specified input (a nonexistent file) gives the correct output (i.e. normal return without uncaught exceptions). JUnit tests fail if they encounter uncaught exceptions, so checking for silent exception-catching may simply be a matter of including a nonexistent file or two in a test. If there's any publicly-observable state or behavior that comes with nonexistent files, though, by all means you should check for that explicitly.

Comment: @JeffBowman Yeah, I understand now. I had just been too caught up in it all and lost track of what I actually needed to write for the test. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a classic example of trying to work against the language, rather than working with it. It might also be an example of code that isn't very testable by design.

First of all, it's important to understand the *conceptual* difference between checked and unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions like `NullPointerException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` are "unchecked" (meaning the compiler doesn't care about them), because when they are thrown, it is usually the fault of the programmer. These kinds of exceptions can usually be easily guarded against with if-statements before method calls. `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException`, on the other hand, are "checked" (meaning the compiler will complain about missing catch/throw), because even if you check that a file exists with the `File#exists()` method before attempting to read it, external events could occur in the meantime causing the file to go missing, or perhaps a harddrive is pulled from the machine as you're reading a file on it. Checked exceptions usually indicate a type of crash state that you have to specifically decide how to recover from, and only you (as the programmer) can make that decision.

Consider your method. How can you tell by the output of the method whether the read operation failed or succeeded with an empty file? You *can't*, because even though the two events are radically different, you are handling them the exact same way. This may or may not be what you want, but it is likely that it is much more appropriate to handle the two cases differently from where you're calling the method. For example, you may want to display a message to the user that "the file is empty" or that "the file does not exist", rather than "no data".

Secondly, the testability issue (which may or may not be an issue, depending on your setup). The only thing that happens in the `catch`-clause (and thus the only indication that an exception was thrown and caught) is the infamous "log and forget" strategy. You are logging the error (instead of handling/reacting to it where appropriate), so to verify that an exception was caught, your only real option is to mock the logger (if your design permits) and verify that its `error()` method was called. If your objective is to verify *that an exception is thrown given certain input*, you can't just check the output, because that just verifies the output - a completely different test. You have to check that the code path resulting from a thrown exception was taken, and in this case, one way to do it would be to mock the logger.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply.

I'll explain my situation further. The method I posted is a simplified version of the method I am using hence why the catch statement just logs the exception. I can assure you that I am actually handling the error.

The method is also simplified such that just a single file is read. In my actual implementation, I list of files are passed to the method to be read. 

Continued...

Comment: Continued...

Would you say it is correct for a test to pass a list of files containing some which do and don't exist and then checking the output. The FileNotFoundException will be handled so that rather than the program stopping execution, the program logs and notifies of a file not existing but continues to read the files which do exist therefore as an output, I would expect the files which do exist to be have been read and those that don't to be logged.

Comment: One way to test _"given an input of files where some exist and some don't, output a list of strings with the contents of the existing files, and call the error() method on a logger for the non-existent files"_ would be to just feed a list of files, and a mock logger, then verify that the mock's error() method was called the expected number of times (with the expected parameters), and that the output is as expected. You could perhaps replace File (or String) with InputStream, which might make stubbing easier (you can specify the "file" contents in the actual test as Strings).